# My visit visa was refused due to large cash deposits. How to address it?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

I need your advice as I was refused a visit visa to go see my daughter for two reasons:

> You have stated that you are employed as a principal nursing officer earning a monthly income of 188776.00 NGN (£98.93) and you do not have an additional income or savings. Whilst I acknowledge your salary coming in your bank statement provided (account ending 0409), I also note that you have some large cash deposits and bank transfers made into your account that are not consistent with your stated salary nor have you declared the origin of these. For instance 3,000,000 NGN (£1,572.19) on 22.01.2024. These cash deposits are not explained, and I am not able to verify the source of these. As a consequence, I am not satisfied that you have given an accurate account of your circumstances, and this undermines the credibility of your application and all of the statements you have made therein.
> • Furthermore, you have said that your daughter sponsors your trip. Home Office records shows that in her Visa application on 06.10.2021 she declared that her mother has been born on 25.08.1972, whilst your date of birth is on 25.08.1967. This discrepancy leads me to doubt your credibility and intentions on visiting the UK. As a consequence, I am not satisfied that you have given an accurate account of your personal and financial circumstances, and this undermines the credibility of your application and all of the statements you have made therein.

The first one was money sent into by account from my son’s company, who is a realtor, and the purpose was to change the roof of my house, which he stated in the subject of the transaction. And then some money from my in-laws for wedding preparations. I don’t know whether to leave the application and apply in 6 months because by then I would have used it for the roofing or I should just apply immediately again and explain the purpose of the money.

For the second reason my daughter made a mistake due to the pressure she was facing because a document needed for her visa application was delayed and the school had said she would defer, so when the document was sent she was in a hurry to get the application done. I think that’s the reason she made that mistake.

Please can you advise on what I should do?

Comment: Funds parking aside, you stated your monthly income is £98, which is the cost of a black cab ride from Heathrow to London. You will have a *very* hard time convincing the UK to let you in if this is your only tie to Nigeria.

Comment: With the difference in the birthdates they don't believe you are really the mother of the person you claim is your daughter. With those three hits against you it's unlikely you are going to the UK.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I also stated I have a house and my mother I am taking care of in Nigeria. Is it advisable to reapply stating the source of the money and the business registration of my son to show it’s from a genuine source and then adding his birth certificates and even pictures of the construction to actually show what the money was met for. Please advise

Comment: @DJClayworth it was an oversight from my daughter during application. Is it possible for her to write a letter stating the reason why she was under pressure and even attaching the emails from her school that she would be deferred if she didn’t receive her ATAS certificate before 11/10/2021  and when she received it on the 4/10/2021 she was in a hurry to get her application done, hence the oversight. Do you she do this and then I attach the letter and emails from school as an evidence. Also her Teir 2 visa application in 2022 had my correct birth year can she call their attention to it?

Comment: @lambshaanxy my application also mentioned that it is a full expense paid trip by my daughter and the first paragraph of the refusal letter states that ‘ You have applied to visit the UK for one month and 1 month and 11 days for tourism to visit your daughter. I acknowledge that your trip is sponsored by your daughter. However, I have to take into account your own personal and financial current circumstances.’

Comment: @Ara Even with a sponsor, you still have to convince UKVI that you personally are a genuine visitor. I don’t see you getting a UK visa any time soon. If I were you I would build up my travel history by meeting up with your daughter in a country you can enter without needing a visa.

Comment: @Traveller Does it mean that even if I’m able to prove the source of the deposit which is my son’s company by attaching all his company’s registration's documents and tax payer documents, providing pictures of the house renovation the money is met for, also the subject of my son’s transaction to me carried ‘roofing’ which they could refer to and see I am just supporting with managing the project and my daughter is submitting a pof up to £15k to show she can support me, do you still think might still be refused the visa

Comment: @Ara No-one can answer that for sure. Do you have a good travel history? UKVI need to be convinced you’ll leave at the end of your trip. See eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e Your daughter provided incorrect/false information in *her own* visa application, at this point I’m not sure I’d want to give UKVI a reason to take a look at that.

Comment: @Traveller thank you so much for answering my questions. I will take time to build my travel history before reapplying in the future. But do you advise that my daughter writes to UKVI about the mistake in my DOD that she made for her first application in 2021 although the correct DOB is there for her 2nd application in 2022, just so it doesn’t affect me in the future when I wish to reapply to visit her?